# How to export C# datatable into Excel with HtmlFormatting

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I am using Asp.NET application with C#, in which having following data table

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("S.No", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("HtmlContent", typeof(int));

                dt.Rows.Add("1", "Hi, I am <b>XXX</b>");
                dt.Rows.Add("2", "<b>Great</b> <i>Work</i>");
                dt.Rows.Add("3","This is Sample Image <img src='smiley.gif' alt='Smiley face' height='42' width='42'>");
                dt.Rows.Add("4", "This is attached file <a href='../Content/FileManager/Documents/Product Review.docx'>../Content/FileManager/Documents/Product Review.docx</a>");
```

In this DataTable, HtmlContent column contains Html Tags, Image tags and File (PDF or Word or Video or Audio) in Link Format.

**Requirement:**

I want to export this data table into excel format, **My Server does not contain MS-Office Excel**, Content should be rendered as Html in Excel cell, If any of the image file is available then displayed within the excel cell, If any of the file (PDF or Word or Video or Audio) available then It should Embed that object into Excel cell.

Kindly refer the attached Image to view my final output.

I have searched online but could not get appropriate solution approach, Kindly provide some help.

Thanks,

Selvakumar S

[image: attached Image]

Comment: Are you aware about the Microsoft Office Interop Assemblies? Would it be possible to install them on the server (not the MS Office, just the interop installer)?

Comment: yes i am aware of Interop assemblies, In google all the link are said, MS-Excel application is needed for Interop assemblies, I don't know exactly but searching for the workable solution  using DLL's without installing anything on server

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) to accomplish the task that you want. As it uses the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll you do not need to install MS-Office Excel in your server. For more information please read ClosedXML's [documentation.](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: Hi i just start exploring OpenXML and ClosedXML, In this i am getting workable solution for Html Content & Inserting images but could not get appropriate solution approach for embedding files, did you know any sample code then it helps me a lot.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25784726/1698964). It may guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

[Essential XlsIO](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/xlsio/defaultfunctionalities.aspx) can export to Excel with HTML formatting. It is written in C# and available as a library for use from any .NET platform. [example source](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/147883/ze/HTML_TO_Excel1585752560.zip)

You need the Syncfusion library in order to run the example code.
The [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) provides the whole suite of products for free if you qualify.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.